# Cannot install Python module

Tags: python, module, pip

I'm having trouble installing modules on Windows, it happened with Pyautogui and PyInstaller. I'm using Python 3.8.6. Here the error from cmd:

```
 C:\Users\Federico>pip install pyautogui
Collecting pyautogui
  Using cached PyAutoGUI-0.9.52.tar.gz (55 kB)
Collecting mouseinfo
  Using cached MouseInfo-0.1.3.tar.gz (10 kB)
Collecting pygetwindow>=0.0.5
  Using cached PyGetWindow-0.0.9.tar.gz (9.7 kB)
Collecting pymsgbox
  Using cached PyMsgBox-1.0.9.tar.gz (18 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'd:\università\programmi\phyton\python38\python.exe' 'd:\università\programmi\phyton\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\Federico\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp38g67qp2'
         cwd: C:\Users\Federico\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-739070l_\pymsgbox_0990b887c8dd4cd6bf35091c71063690
    Complete output (14 lines):
    running dist_info
    creating C:\Users\Federico\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-16fa8xeg\PyMsgBox.egg-info
    writing C:\Users\Federico\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-16fa8xeg\PyMsgBox.egg-info\PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to C:\Users\Federico\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-16fa8xeg\PyMsgBox.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
    writing top-level names to C:\Users\Federico\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-16fa8xeg\PyMsgBox.egg-info\top_level.txt
    writing manifest file 'C:\Users\Federico\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-16fa8xeg\PyMsgBox.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest file 'C:\Users\Federico\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-16fa8xeg\PyMsgBox.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
    Error in sitecustomize; set PYTHONVERBOSE for traceback:
    SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe0 in position 0: unexpected end of data (sitecustomize.py, line 7)
    warning: no files found matching '*.py' under directory 'pymsgbox'
    writing manifest file 'C:\Users\Federico\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-16fa8xeg\PyMsgBox.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    creating 'C:\Users\Federico\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-16fa8xeg\PyMsgBox.dist-info'
    error: invalid command 'bdist_wheel'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'd:\università\programmi\phyton\python38\python.exe' 'd:\università\programmi\phyton\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\Federico\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp38g67qp2' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: try `pip install wheel`

Comment: Also try `py -m pip install pyautogui`, if it still doesn't work

Comment: @Etoneja, thanks. Now it works!